# why createfile function in c stop the for loop

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to create a script that gets arguments, for each argument creates a file with the argument as content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    HANDLE hfile;
    char *filename;
    char *data;
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        data = argv[i];
        printf(data);
        sprintf(filename, "C://temp//%d.txt",i);
        printf(filename);
        hfile = CreateFile(
            filename,
            GENERIC_WRITE,  
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
        );
        printf("asdasd");
        BOOL writetofile;
        writetofile = WriteFile(
            hfile,
            data,
            strlen(data),
            0,
            NULL
        );
        printf("done");
    }
}
```

after debugging as you can see with the printfs, the script only run the loop one time.
command line:

```
./a.exe a b c d
```

output:

```
a
```

Comment: `"C://temp/%d.txt"` -> `"C:/temp/%d.txt"` ?

Comment: ... and did you debug this? Obviously not. You don't test if `CreateFile` actually succeeds? And you don't close the file either, which is probably the main problem here. But there are most likely more problems.

Comment: By default, when `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is connected to a terminal or console, it's *line buffered*, meaning that output is actually flushed (and written to the console) on newline. You don't have any newlines when you print, so the output might not happen when you expect.

Comment: `filename` should be allocated

Comment: _"I tested the CreateFile"_, no you don't, at least not in the code you provided.

Comment: because your output stop at `printf(data);` , issue must be between `printf(data);` and `printf(filename);` meaning that `CreateFile` is not likely to be the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems. Here 5 off the top of my head:

1. `filename` cannot be `char *` if you want to use `sprintf`. It needs a valid memory buffer.
2. Yout need to use `/` not `//`.
3. You need to use `CloseHandle()` after writing into file for closing file.
4. `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` cannot be `NULL` for `WriteFile()`.
5. Always check if file is opened correctly.

So this is the simplest code that I can think of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    HANDLE hfile;
    char filename[50] = {0,};
    char *data;
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        data = argv[i];
        printf(data);
        sprintf(filename, "C:/temp/%d.txt",i);
        printf(filename);
        hfile = CreateFile(
            filename,
            GENERIC_WRITE,  
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL
        );

        printf("asdasd");
        if (hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            DWORD writtenSize = 0;
            BOOL writetofile = WriteFile(
                hfile,
                data,
                strlen(data),
                &writtenSize,
                NULL
           );

           if (writetofile) {
               printf("write done.");
           }

           CloseHandle(hfile);
        }

        printf("done");
    }
}
```

Though it may not be a good idea to use fixed buffer size for `filename`, I think I correct most of code errors.

Comment: I fixed 2 and 3, thank you! which data type should I use for filename?

Comment: @Fusu How about an array large enough? Or at the very least make `filename` point somewhere valid.

Comment: @Fusu  you can remove your comments to Jabberwocky. I'll remove this one too in a while.